# How can two tikz arrow tips be superimposed?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm like two superimposed two arrow heads in tikz, e.g. given the arrow tips `Latex` and `Circle`, have a way of getting a new arrow tip `SuperposeLatexCircle` such that `\draw [-{SuperposeLatexCircle}] (A) -- (B)` is equivalent to `\draw [-{Latex}] (A) -- (B); \draw [-{Circle}] (A) -- (B)`.

I think this should be doable using `sep`, e.g. `\draw [-{Latex[sep=-1pt]Circle}] (A) -- (B)` with `1pt` replaced by a better value. The relevant values should be:

- Default `sep`: `0.88pt .3 1`
- [Default `length` for `Latex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/247f1f0445a9e996560c9f5a9b3fb03a4184e6ec/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex#L812): `+3pt 4.5 .8`

I tried taking `sep=-3.88pt -4.8 0.9` (the first two components are `-0.88pt-3pt` and `-.3-4.5` respectively, and I did not know what to put for the third one so I put the average of `1` and `.8`. This does not work but is fairly close when replacing `Circle` by `Diamond`.

The problem with `Circle` is probably that its length is very different from the lengths of `Latex`, so we probably also need the default length of `Circle`:

- [Default `length` for `Circle`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/247f1f0445a9e996560c9f5a9b3fb03a4184e6ec/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex#L1219): `+2.39365pt +3.191538`

---

Candidate methods before I had before thinking about `sep`:

Any of the following would help (in decreasing order of preference):

- A way of combining arrows without needing to predeclare them, e.g. `\draw [-{Superpose[first=Latex, second=Circle]}] (A) -- (B)`;

Edit: I'm stating to think that it is possible to do this with a negative `sep`, e.g. `-{Latex[sep=-1pt]Circle}`, but I'm not sure how to compute the correct sep automatically.

- A way of declaring combinations without copying and pasting, e.g. using `pgfarrowsdeclarecombine` plus some shifting to cancel the movement between the two arrows, or something like

```
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=CombineLatexCircle,
  % ...
  drawing code={
    \pgf@ar@code@Latex
    \pgf@ar@code@Circle
  },
  % ...
}
```

(This seems hard to do for some components of the definition)

- Some systematic way of copying and pasting that allows to combine two `\pgfdeclarearrow` declarations, e.g. "Concatenate the drawing codes, discard the defaults, change all names in setup and drawing code to avoid clashes, ..."

Comment: Interesting question. I can see this being useful. Please open a feature request at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues. Something like `\draw[-{LaTeX,Circle}]` should actually be possible to implement.

Comment: Please post a compilable MWE that people can use as a starting point.

Comment: `[-Latex,postaction={draw,-Circle}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. Define a style that places the circle tip at the end of the segment and call it with the `Latex` arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    circarr/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{Circle}}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (1,0); \draw [-{Circle}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [-{Latex}, circarr] (0,.5) -- (1,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could have `circarr` draw both arrowheads:

```
\tikzset{
    circarr/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark={at position 1 with {\arrow{Circle}}, at position 1 with {\arrow{Latex}}}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
```

Which creates the same output as above using `\draw [circarr] (0,.5) -- (1,.5);`. You could make another style for the arrows at the beginning of the segment using `position 0` and `\arrowreversed` instead of `\arrow`.

Here is a MWE with `circarrb` (beginning) and `circarre` (end) both implemented:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    circarre/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark={at position 1 with {\arrow{Circle}}, at position 1 with {\arrow{Latex}}}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    },
    circarrb/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark={at position 0 with {\arrowreversed{Circle}}, at position 0 with {\arrowreversed{Latex}}}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [circarre] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [circarrb] (0,.5) -- (1,.5);
\draw [circarrb,circarre] (0,1) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`/tikz/tips` (and `/pgf/tips`) is the option that controls
whether arrows are drawn when the base path is a degenerated one
or when the it is not `draw`n.

For `tips=true`, the arrow will be drawn whatsoever,
even though the base path is not drawn.
So I use it with `postaction`

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \draw[tips=true,
            postaction=-Latex,
            postaction=-Circle,
            postaction=-|,
        ]
            (0,0)--(1,0);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But there is one caveat, though. Consider what the `bending` module would do: it shortens the path so arrows fit in. How much should it shorten in this case? 0 or the max of length?